# i need to modify rowCallback jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Working on **django**. Need to modify **rowCallback** jquery. Page is loading with multipleSelect 
dataTable and have server based pagination. Now i want to **change the color of one column** on the base of data.
And I couldn't understand what is happening inside this rowCallback function as the documentation is not helping for me.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    if ( data.grade == "A" ) {
      $('td:eq(4)', row).html( '<b>A</b>' );
    }
  }
} );
```

Can anyone explains last 2 lines, I am kind of new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the code inside the rowCallback function

```
if ( data.grade == "A" ) {
  $('td:eq(4)', row).html( '<b>A</b>' );
}
```

This basically is validating if the grade is A for each row, and in case it is A, then it applies the selector for the 4th tab in your table and for that given row, and changes the html to the value of bold A.

Comment: is the syntax right. if column name is LicenseIssueDate and from all the data only values above than 5 should become orange"rowCallback": codeis......                            
   function( row, data ) {
    if ( data.LicenseIssueDate > 5 ) {
      $('td', row).css("background-color", "Orange");
    }
  },

Comment: The syntax is right, and it is doing what i told you. In case you want to change the behavior, it all depends on what you want to do. LicenseIssueDate looks like a date, and doing this comparison (LicenseIssueDate  > 5) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Now i get it, thanks for your time. Sometimes documentation is hard to understand.